# How "commutative" is matrix multiplication with identity matrices?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

A property of matrix multiplication is that, if $A$ & $B$ & $C$ are matrices

- $A(BC) = (AB)C$ (associative)
- $A(B+C)$ = $AB + AC$ and $(A + B)C = AC + BC$ (distributive)
- $AB ≠ BA$ (not commutative)

And if $A$ is invertible and $AB=I$, then $BA=I$, hence B is the inverse of A, then:

$AB = I$

$A^{-1}AB = A^{-1}I$

$IB = A^{-1}I$

$B = A^{-1}$

$BA = A^{-1}A = I$

and I want to find X - an unknown matrix.
This is true:

$AX = C $

$A^{-1} AX = A^{-1} C$

$IX = A^{-1}C$

$X = A^{-1} C$

But is the below variation also correct according to the matrix definitions and why?
Does it matter where $A^{-1}$ is on the RHS, before or after $C$?
Does it make a difference if $I$ is before or after $X$? The matrix definition says it is not commutative so the output is $IX ≠ XI$?

$XA = C$

$XAA^{-1} = CA^{-1}$

$XI = CA^{-1}$

$X = CA^{-1}$

Comment: Yes $IX = X = XI$.  The identity matrix commutes with everything.  And no, $CA^{-1}$ is not necessarily equal to $A^{-1}C$, just as $AX$ is not necessarily equal to $XA$.  You got the different expressions from having started at different places.

Comment: Note that if $X$ is not a square matrix, it is not the same identity matrix.

Comment: @Gribouillis do you mean that if $X$ must be a square matrix for this to work?

Comment: "$AB\neq BA.$" This is dangerous notation, because it implies they are never equal, which is not true. Indeed, commutativity is true for all $1\times 1$ matrices, and for $n\times n$ matrices with $n>1,$ it is true in certain circumstances.

Comment: If $A$ is a square matrix (which it must be for $A^{-1}$ to exist,) and $AX$ and $XA$ are both defined, then $X$ must be square matrix of the same size.

Comment: You have correctly solved two **different** equations, $AX=C$ and $XA=C$. So it's n ot surprising that the solutions, $A^{-1}C$ and $CA^{-1}$ are usually different.

Comment: @Chris I mean that if $X$ has $m$ rows and $p$ columns, the relation is $I_m X = X = X I_p$ where $I_k$ is the identity of size $k\times k$.